# Apple Metal Frame Capture does not work in Xcode 15

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, metal

I find it lately almost impossible to capture a Metal Frame.

This is so for my own Apps (all iOS Apps) as well as for sample Metal macOS and Metal iOS Apps downloaded freshly from Apple website (https://developer.apple.com/metal/sample-code/), even for minimal Metal project the problem is there.

1. Either the "Capture" button under "M" is grayed out (and fps shows 0), so I can not click it. (Happens for both iOS Apps and MacOS Apps.)

[image]

2. Or clicking "M" says the device can not be connected to  (observed for MacOS Apps only, but happens both on M2 Mac and on Intel/AMD Mac).

[image]

3. In case the "Capture" button is NOT grayed out, and I CAN click it, the replay just spins forever. (For iOS Apps and macOS Apps.)

[image]

4. Capturing a gputrace programmatically with MTLCaptureManager and writing to url works, but when I want to replay the .gputrace document in XCode it also does not replay (spins forever). (For iOS Apps and macOS Apps.)

[image]

5. There is some error message in the console (only observed for iOS Apps), but that appears always when I just run the project, so not sure if it is related to capture/debug.

[image]

Other (maybe) relevant information:

- The Apps run all in Debug configuration.
- The Apps themselves run completely normally with expected fps with the Metal HUD reflecting that.
- Until a couple of weeks ago, my Metal projects (all iOS) never had problems with Metal Debugger and Capture and I have not edited any Scheme setting or pList, so Capture is enabled.
- Also any Apple sample Metal Apps (iOS or MacOS) never had problems before.
- My Macs (one M2, one Intel/AMD) running Xcode use MacOS 14.2.1.
- My iPads(2019, 2022) run iPadOS 17.2 and my iPhone12 runs iOS 17.2.1.
- The Macs use different developer account, so there are in this sense 'independent'.
- Specifically for iOS Apps: I tested in various 'combinations' (so one of the two Macs compiling for one of the three iPhone/iPad devices) and the problems remains. Restarting device (iPad or iPhone) alone does not help.
- Problems observed with XCode 15.1 and 15.2.
- Disabling the Metal HUD does not help.
- The only thing that helps usually (but after a handful of compiles the problem returns) is:
  removing XCode project build files (caches, data and indices), removing /Developer/Xcode/DerivedData, restarting the Mac, removing the App from the device, for  iOS Apps restarting the device, and recompiling. After that, usually a Frame Capture and Replay succeeds. If I skip one of these steps, the problem remains. And after several compiles the problem returns. Only restarting Xcode never helps. For iOS Apps, only restarting the device never helps.

My question: How can I capture a frame in Metal? (Is this a bug, has anyone else got these problems, is there a workaround?)

Comment: Are you running an iOS app or macOS app or both? If it's iOS, have you tried restarting the target device after enabling the developer mode? (If you have been developing on it for a while, then the mode is enabled, just try to restart the device).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I edited my question based on the details you pointed out as missing.  Restarting the device was actually the very first thing I tried, but that fixes nothing.

Comment: This has been happening to me for months. Filed several bugs, even requested Code Level Support from Apple. Nothing works consistently. If I restart everything and sacrifice a chicken, sometimes it works for a few runs, then gets backs to either crashing or hanging. Sad state of things as blindly debugging GPU issues is about as unproductive as it gets (and the Metal debugger, when it works, is actually really great). Not sure what's going on with Apple on this one.

Comment: I have the same issue with xcode 15.1. I can't get a capture of Metal sample code projects on MacOS, iOS or tvOS.

Comment: Thank you very much both for your comments. That is a bad situation, but based on your feedback and also some discussions about this I have seen on X and in Apple Developer Forums, at least I know now that it is nothing that I am doing wrong.

Comment: I am using XCode 15.3. and iPadOS 17.4 since a couple of days now and the Metal Frame Debugger seems to work again.